# Best way to reattach laptop hinge

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair

I'll make this short and sweet since I've seen a lot of laptop hinge threads. The pieces I circled in red somehow came apart. I'm unsure how they were attached to begin with. It almost looks like belt screws. What's the best way to reattach them? I'm hesitant to use epoxy because it may not last long.

[image]

Comment: *The pieces I circled in red ... It almost looks like belt screws.* It looks like rivets, not screws. But if there is enough space for locknuts you may use (short screw + locknut) pairs instead.

Comment: Since the bottom lays flat against case there's not enough room. As an update, Epoxy did not hold

Comment: There are screws that you can countersink, that or see if a new hinge is available.